# Firebase Funtions not showing after deploy with new changes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I copied an email-confimation cloud function from sample-function and deployed it to my project, it work and that function is showing in my firebase console.

However, after I custom the code according to my needs and then deploy to firebase, the function just disappear from my firebase functions.

The original code is:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

// Sends an email confirmation when a user changes his mailing list subscription.
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onWrite((event) => {
  const snapshot = event.data;
  const val = snapshot.val();

  if (!snapshot.changed('subscribedToMailingList')) {
    return null;
  }

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Spammy Corp." <noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: val.email,
  };

  const subscribed = val.subscribedToMailingList;

  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = subscribed ? 'Thanks and Welcome!' : 'Sad to see you go :`(';
  mailOptions.text = subscribed ? 'Thanks you for subscribing to our newsletter. You will receive our next weekly newsletter.' : 'I hereby confirm that I will stop sending you the newsletter.';

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(() => console.log(`New ${subscribed ? '' : 'un'}subscription confirmation email sent to:`, val.email))
    .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));
});
```

And the updated code is:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

// Sends an email confirmation when a user changes his mailing list subscription.
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.subject === undefined || req.body.recipient === undefined) {
    // This is an error case, as "message" is required.
    //res.status(400).send('subject/body/recipient is missing!');
    return false
  } else {
      const mailSubject = req.body.subject;
      const mailHtmlBody = req.body.htmlBody;
      const mailRecipient = req.body.recipient;



      const mailOptions = {
        from: '"Food Ninja." <foodninjaapp@gmail.com>',
        to:  mailRecipient,
        subject: mailSubject,
        html: mailHtmlBody
      };

      //res.status(200).send('Success: ' + mailSubject + ' to ' + mailRecipient);

      return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
//        .then(() => console.log(`${mailSubject}subscription confirmation email sent to: `, mailRecipient))
//        .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));
  }
};
```

So far i don see anything wrong with the code, please advise.

**Edited**

How i deploy it:

```
firebase deploy
```

And here is the response from the Cmder for new code deployment:

```
=== Deploying to 'food-ninja-mobile'...               

i  deploying database, functions, hosting             
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint


> functions@ lint C:\Users\jerry.ho\Documents\ADA\Proj
ects\foodNinjaCloudFunction\email-confirmation\functio
ns                                                    
> eslint .                                            

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.      
i  database: checking rules syntax...                 
+  database: rules syntax for database food-ninja-mobi
le is valid                                           
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...  
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled          
i  functions: preparing functions directory for upload
ing...                                                
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...  
+  hosting: 4 files uploaded successfully             
i  database: releasing rules...                       
+  database: rules for database food-ninja-mobile rele
ased successfully                                     
i  functions: deleting function sendEmailConfirmation.
..                                                    
+  functions[sendEmailConfirmation]: Successful delete
 operation.                                           

+  Deploy complete!                                   

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/p
roject/food-ninja-mobile/overview                     
Hosting URL: https://food-ninja-mobile.firebaseapp.com
```

Here is the response from the original code deployment:

```
=== Deploying to 'food-ninja-mobile'...

i  deploying database, functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\...\---local path---
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  database: checking rules syntax...
+  database: rules syntax for database food-ninja-mobile is valid
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (52.54 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...
+  hosting: 4 files uploaded successfully
i  database: releasing rules...
+  database: rules for database food-ninja-mobile released successfully
i  functions: creating function sendEmailConfirmation...
+  functions[sendEmailConfirmation]: Successful create operation.

+  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/food-ninja-mobile/overview
Hosting URL: https://food-ninja-mobile.firebaseapp.com
```

Comment: How do you deploy the function? And what is the output that you get when you deploy it?

Comment: i have updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jerry The function did not work because, you have replaced this function call with your own function

```
functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onWrite
```

This line is the **trigger** for your function, so naturally, the function is not working now.

When you deploy your cloud functions, always look at the logs generated.
Like for eg: if you deploy your old code now, the logs will say "**sendEmailConfirmation function is created**"

If you update the content of the same function it will log, "**sendEmailConfirmation function is updated**"

If you remove or delete the function, it will log,
"**sendEmailConfirmation function is deleted**"

Hope this helps.

Edited after getting the comment:

```
    exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onWrite((event) => {
          const snapshot = event.data;
          const val = snapshot.val();

          if (!snapshot.changed('subscribedToMailingList')) {
            return null;
          }

//instead of getting from the request, have the mail variables either in a firebase node or for now just hard code it. for email, get it from the variable val
    const mailSubject = "This is my mail subject";
          const mailHtmlBody ="this is a awesome mail";
          const mailRecipient = val.email;



          const mailOptions = {
            from: '"Food Ninja." <foodninjaapp@gmail.com>',
            to:  mailRecipient,
            subject: mailSubject,
            html: mailHtmlBody
          };




          return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
            .then(() => console.log(`New ${subscribed ? '' : 'un'}subscription confirmation email sent to:`, val.email))
            .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));
        });
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, it did help me understand why when deploying new code it will show the function is deleted in my console. But i still not very clear on how it work because i did replace a new function there. Can you show me how to change the function or any documentation explain these in details? **i updated the post with the response from console.

Comment: I have edited your sample code with few lines from your updated code. Try running this and see if it works

Comment: Based on your code, is that mean we can't change the existing function? The thing we can do is exporting another new function in the same file?